# Undoing accidental hg amend on top of Mercurial queue

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

The following sequence of commands requires that the Mercurial Queues exension be enabled, and also the Evolve extension (for `hg amend`, alias `hg refresh`).

This combination of commands messes up the existing Mercurial queue, making the commit corresponding to the pushed patch obsolete, and creating a new commit with exactly the same contents.

This error is in theory quite easy to make: just type `hg ref` instead of `hg qref`, but I just made it recently after using Mercurial Queues for years. Regardless, I haven't figured out a clean way to fix this and get back the original state.

Note that a simple `hg rollback` does work in my example, but I'm not sure it will work in my case, because I've tried other things trying to fix this. In any case, `hg rollback` isn't something one should rely on.
In summary, how do I undo the `hg amend` and get back my applied MQ patch?

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                

hg init test
cd test
echo "This is foo" >> foo
hg add
hg ci -m "Add foo"
hg init --mq
echo "Line 2 of foo" >> foo
hg qnew p
hg ci --mq -m "Add patch p"
hg ref


hg log -vG --hidden
@  changeset:   2:f7f038d3aab5
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      0:9d3a95922194
|  user:        Faheem Mitha <faheem@faheem.info>
|  date:        Sun Mar 11 16:38:51 2018 +0530
|  files:       foo
|  description:
|  [mq]: p
|
|
| x  changeset:   1:e467a2433c7f
|/   tag:         p
|    tag:         qbase
|    tag:         qtip
|    user:        Faheem Mitha <faheem@faheem.info>
|    date:        Sun Mar 11 16:38:50 2018 +0530
|    obsolete:    rewritten using amend as 2:f7f038d3aab5 by Faheem Mitha <faheem@faheem.info> (at 2018-03-11 16:38 +0530)
|    obsolete:    rewritten by Faheem Mitha <faheem@faheem.info> as f7f038d3aab5 (at 2018-03-11 16:38 +0530)
|    files:       foo
|    description:
|    [mq]: p
|
|
o  changeset:   0:9d3a95922194
   tag:         qparent
   user:        Faheem Mitha <faheem@faheem.info>
   date:        Sun Mar 11 16:38:50 2018 +0530
   files:       foo
   description:
   Add foo
```

Comment: See https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5816

Answer (score 1):

That's not what I get with your test case. I need an additional

```
echo "Line 3" >> foo
```

before the hg ref. Also, versioning your mq seems irrelevant here; I think you can remove the `hg init --mq` and `hg ci --mq` lines.

hg amend really ought to block that. But if you wanted to manually fix things up, edit .hg/patches/series and replace the obsolete hash with the successor's hash. (Just make sure to use the 20-byte hash, as is given by eg `hg log -T '{node}\n'`).

Warning: when I tried that with your test case and qpopped, something mysteriously un-obsoleted the old head, and it gives a strange warning about the current directory not being a head (despite `hg log -r 'head()'` listing it.) But at least you have your queue back in a working state.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Some comments... First I don't understand why you need an additional line in "foo". Can you doublecheck that?

Comment: because if I don't, then `hg refresh` just says "nothing changed" (correctly).

Comment: To be specific, my reproduction case is `hg init test; cd test; echo line1 > foo; hg add foo; hg commit -m init; echo line2 >> foo; hg qnew mypatch; echo line3 >> foo; hg amend; hg qpop`

Comment: (and the corresponding fix would be to replace the last line of .hg/patches/status with the output of `hg log -r . -T '{node}:mypatch\n'`)